# Multiple operations in Java AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am developing an android app that will access a Microsoft SQL Server database. I have read over the Internet that I should use `AsyncTask`. The problem is I have a lot of different independent functions that read/write data to the DB, do I have to write an `AsyncTask` for each function? Is there any suggestion rather than the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828359/asynctask-multiple-different-operations)?

Comment: There are 2 main network libraries they have both asynchronous ops you can go through them.. **volley** and **retrofit**

Comment: AsyncTask is for performing tasks in background thread to prevent blocking the UI thread. It depends on you implementation, you can create a class that extends AsyncTask to perform repetitive tasks.

Comment: or you can also use **Rxjava2** it can operate on multiple async tasks..

Answer (score 0):

If they are sequential method calls just call them in one AsyncTask. Other than that maybe you want to create a Service and perform all your read/write operations there.